# In access update contact information while retaining record of old in database

Tags: ms-access, referential-integrity

In Microsoft Access I have three tables: order table, customer table and product table. My order table pulls in both customer contact and product information. Every now and then I need to update either the customer address. When doing so, I only want the new address to appear on future orders. I don't want Access to update previous orders with an address that was not originally affiliated with that order. I also want to maintain a list of active and past addresses on the customer list. Please advise on the best ways for setting up the customer table and how to retain customer contact information on the order table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you need to take the customer address out of the Customer table and keep it in a separate CustomerAddress table. This new table has a primary key (of course), a foreign key back to the Customer table, all the address fields that you want to maintain history of and a Current flag (Yes/No). Your Order table then points directly to the CustomerAddress table instead of the Customer table (you can get from Order to Customer because of the FK link on CustomerAddress to Customer). Now your fun starts! You have to maintain your CustomerAddress table in such a way that for each Customer ID you should only have one Address record where Current is True.

The other alternative is to not have a Current flag on the CustomerAddress table, but instead have a CurrentAddress field in your Customer table - this ensures that only one Address can ever be the current one for a Customer. However you can't enforce both the CurrentAddress integrity and the CustomerAddress foreign key - you can't set the value of CurrentAddress until you've added the Address record, so Customer record has to be able to exist with NULL CurrentAddress (although I suppose you could have a dummy 'Not set' CustomerAddress record).

Answer (score 1):

The simple method is to store the current customer information with the order.

The extended method is to store the customer table(s) as *temporal* tables, either using a custom method or a native as - for example - offered by the newest versions of *SQL Server*. Look up the term *Temporal database* for more information.

Comment: I'd opt for the first suggestion made by @Skippy. With one change, do not use a Current Flag (Yes/No) but rather use a date range (Valid from and Valid to date field). Reason being it might happen that a customer sends you an address change in advance.